# Mozilla scale3d() ignores <SELECT> elements

Tags: html, css, transform

I think this is a bug with Mozilla (Firefox) up through the present 17.0.1. Hopefully folks have work arounds.

See the example http://jsfiddle.net/dd3pQ/

The CSS3 property *scale3d* scales the elements in a page, but ignores the `OPTION` elements of the `SELECT` drop down list. As you can see, they are rendered to the left of where they should be, in the page they would have originally been if not scaled.

We need to use scale3d in our app, but we also need drop down lists. Is this possible with Mozilla right now?

Comment: I think that occurs because the OS renders the dropdowns. The same happens in Chrome. You could make your own custom dropdowns with HTML/CSS and your current code would work just fine with those.

Comment: @Blender thx for the response. I was hoping to use my existing widgets rather than build new ones from custom HTML to emulate the `SELECT` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown is rendered by the operating system, and the OS doesn't give browsers hooks to style it.

Because form elements are limited by the OS capabilities, CSS doesn't require browsers to style them at all (they are "replaced elements" in CSS terminology, like contents of `<img>`). So, technically, that's not a bug.

Comment: Happened to read http://paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/, `Now, what’s not shared in WebKit ports:` yesterday and thought of this. While FF is Gecko, not WK, it is the same issue.

Comment: I hate to accept the answer that there is no answer, but that seems to be the case. Sadly I've seem a number of these issues were browser impl's don't try to go the extra mile.

Comment: @JosephLust it used to be much worse. Safari 1.0 didn't allow any styling of controls. It wouldn't even change color of buttons. And it's a dilemma: to get proper native look'n'feel browsers should use system's controls instead of faking their own.

Comment: True, but when you scale the `Select` box, but not the `Options` it's just a halfassed implementation.